# get the value instead of the object from python regex search

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I wrote a small python program to find mobile numbers from a file using python's re.search() function.

What I get is an output as below

So, functionally, the script is working fine. However, it gives me more details. How can I modify to just get the mobile number?

```
for line in fhandle:
    #s10 occurences of digits
    number = re.search("[0-9]{10}",line)
    numberList.append(number)

for num in numberList:
    print(num)
```

Comment: more details? Like?

Comment: `numberList.append(number.group(0))`

Comment: Add a plain python tag please

Comment: @Nick. If you add the tag, I'll dupe hammer it

Comment: @MadPhysicist done

Comment: @Nick. Thanks. Good teamwork